# refresh div to retrieve information from database without refreshing wholepage

Tags: php, jquery

I would like to refreash the div `auto` every 2 seconds without reloading the page how can i do this with jquery i did try some solutions but they did not work if can help that would be great

**conversation.php**

```
<?php
        $hash =$run_con['hash'];
        while($run_message = mysql_fetch_assoc($message_query))
            {

                 $from_id = $run_message['from_id'];
                 $message = $run_message['message'];

                $user_query = mysql_query("SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `id`='$from_id'");
                $run_user = mysql_fetch_array($user_query);
                $from_username = $run_user['username'];


                echo "<div id='auto'<p><b>$from_username</b><br />$message</p>  </div>"; //reload this part every 2 seconds


            }
    ?>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
    $("#auto").load('conversation.php'+$hash)
    }, 2000);
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: You can do it with jquery. And if your solutions didn't work - you've been doing it wrong. But cauze you don't show us your js-code - we can do nothing, sorry.

Comment: Not sure if I got you currectly. But you can set a timer with jQuery that calls a PHP function using Ajax and changes the div's values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make a query every 2 seconds that doesn't refresh the page itself, you'll need to use jQuery and AJAX. For this to work, you should create a file of it's own with the query that is being called every 2 seconds.

Let's start with the jQuery.

For this script to actually work, you'll need to include jQuery. Inside the HTML `<head></head>`-tags on your page, include the following line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

Without this, you can't run any jQuery functions. Now that you have included this, you can build the actual script.

To explain a bit on how this works, I've created a function called `ajaxCall`. This function executes the script inside `ajax.php`, and when it's successful with that, it replaced the output from `ajax.php` with the content on your div that has an id `div1`, on the current page. This action is performed once when the page is loaded (`ajaxCall();`) and every 2 seconds after that.

```
<script>
function ajaxCall() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php", 
        success: (function (result) {
            $("#div1").html(result);
        })
    })
};

ajaxCall(); // To output when the page loads
setInterval(ajaxCall, (2 * 1000)); // x * 1000 to get it in seconds
</script>
```

Place this script in the same file where you want the `div1` to be reloaded (of course you can rename it as whatever you please, just be persistent).

So your `conversation.php` should now have...

- included the jQuery libary
- the script to perform the AJAX-call
- a div with id "div1" (`<div id="div1"></div>`), where the contents of `ajax.php` will be put.

As for your `ajax.php` file, this is where you'll actually perform your query. For your case, that would be where you put

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass");
mysql_select_db("database");

// Other variables needed to perform the query, such as $message_query
// needs to be here as well

while ($run_message = mysql_fetch_assoc($message_query)) {
    $from_id = $run_message['from_id'];
    $message = $run_message['message'];

    $user_query = mysql_query("SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `id`='$from_id'");
    $run_user = mysql_fetch_array($user_query);
    $from_username = $run_user['username'];

    echo "<p><b>$from_username</b><br />$message</p>";
}
?>
```

---

You should [**stop using `mysql_*` functions**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) if you can, as they are deprecated and no longer maintained. In addition, usage of `mysqli_*` or PDO will enable usage of prepared statements, so that you can prevent [SQL-injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Answer (score 3):

Change this line

```
$("#auto").load('conversation.php'+$hash)}, 2000);
```

to this

```
$("#auto").load('conversation.php'+'<?php echo $hash?>')}, 2000);
```

Because your `$hash` is PHP variable, but you are not inside a PHP block, you are unable to access it.